# Setting the maximum number of users Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So this is a pretty straight forward question. I have an app, And I want to have N maximum number of users. Originally, I had planned to use something like:

```
  mFirestore.collection("Users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
               if(task.isSuccessful()){
                   for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult()){
                       numUsers++;
                   }
               }

            }
        });
```

Then on register, simply check if that number is less than or equal to N before creating the new user.

However, since I haven't logged in, I'm not able to access the user count by counting the documents in the `Users` collection. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written now can be circumvented by a malicious user.  Code on the client can't be trusted to execute correctly.

The only way to enforce this securely is to write a [Cloud Functions authentication trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) that counts the number of times a user has created an account.  If the limit is exceeded, it can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) to [delete the account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) that was just created that exceeded the limit.

Comment: I looked into the Admin SDK a few days ago and when I imported, it replaced `FirebaseAuth`.  Is there any way I can use both? I'm searching on that and I can't find anything. Since I use `auth` to create my users, I'd have to restructure quite a bit of some code, Can I use both?

Comment: The admin SDK is not meant for use in client code.  It's for code deployed to a secure backend you control.